# Can you set/reverse the starting index of the DataGridView rows?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am creating a WPF form that requires a data table to represent different cell statuses using colors. I am using a DataGridView and creating cells depending on what file I decide to upload. The configuration for the data table is represented in 2 different types of files: a .xml and a .prd file. The .xml file is properly represented in the table since the rows and columns start at the correct point. The .prd file assigns the last row in the table as the first row.

eg. The .xml file has row[0] as row[0], but the .prd file has row[24] as row[0].

I need the DataGridView to not just represent the data, but also visually depict how the orientation is supposed to look. I just can't seem to figure out how to reverse the rows index.

Here is my code for the creation of the DataGridView for both types of files:

```
     private void GenerateDataGridView(DataGridView dgv, int rows, int columns)
    {
        if (XMLSelected == true)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= rows; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                    dgv.Columns.Add(null, null);
                else
                    dgv.Columns.Add("rows" + j, "row " + j);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                dgv.Rows.Add("column " + i);
            }
            XMLSelected = false;
        }
        else if(PRDSelected == true)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= rows; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                    dgv.Columns.Add(null, null);
                else
                    dgv.Columns.Add("rows" + j, "row " + j);
                
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= columns; i++)
            {

                if (columns - i > 0)
                {
                    dgv.Rows.Add("column " + (columns - i));
                }
            }
            PRDSelected = false;
        }

    }
```

Just an FYI, the row headings are actually "columns 1,2,3..." and the column headings are "row 1, 2, 3..." so, for the .prd file, I need the "columns" to start from the highest value both in text and index from the top and decrease as it creates each row.

Comment: You could do something like `prdIndex = rows - 1 - j;`

Comment: @hijinxbassist, where would you suggest I add that? and is that an int or something else?

Comment: That would be the "reversed" index.  `j` represents the indices from `0 to n - 1` in your loop.  with `j = 0` and `n = 25`, `p (n - 1 - j)` would be 24 (the first prd item at the last index).

Comment: I just noticed that you are using `<=` in your loop, in which case `-1` would not be needed.  It looks like maybe there is a header row at the first index?

Comment: Right but how would I actually set it so that the DataGridView property RowIndex is changed? I can already make it print the text so that the highest point is max value of columns but I need to change the property. Also the second loop is most likely the loop of focus here since I need to change the dgv.Rows index values. The headers for those rows are just "column x".

Comment: Im trying to recreate it here on my end, but have a couple questions.  Why are the rows created using the `int columns`, and columns being created using the `int rows`?  I would expect `rows` to be the number of rows, and `columns` to be the number of columns.

Comment: I'm doing this for my work and the data table is supposed to represent a tray that hold different devices for testing. The tray orientation is supposed to be rows along the shorter side and columns along the longer side. The system that incorporates those trays has them orientated so that the longer side is vertical.

Comment: Ok, that makes a bit more sense, i was scratching my head thinking something was incorrect there.  So it looks like what my original suggestion was is already represented for the dgv.Rows.  Is it dgv.Columns that is ordered incorrectly?  There is a DisplayIndex in which you can change the order of the dgv.Columns, it looks like the dgv.Rows are added correctly?

Comment: I don't get it. If you want data to look a certain way, load it into a DataTable in a certain order, disable sorting on the grid view and bind the grid view to the table. If you want a rowindex that runs in reverse or something, put a column of data called RowIndex in the datatable and fill it with a descending number. If you don't want it to show in the gridview that's fine; don't put a column for it